# secure site access

Tags: feature-request, http

Why can't I access SO and others through https? I believe it should have a https interface.

Answer (score 6):

Hmm. I can't see a compelling reason for this.

Your login is handled through your OpenID provider, so somebody eavesdropping on the communication between SO and you would not be able to get your password.

As far as I can see, all interaction with the SO site is stuff that is visible publicly anyway, except for votes, flags and ignored tags and such. That is private info, but hardly so security relevant that encrypted communication would make sense. Is it?

Comment: Same reason as to why google has https access to search - what pages you visit and when is not publicly available information.

Comment: How does the site associate your request with you OpenID account? Cookies. They are sent as HTTP headers, thus easy to eavesdrop on unencrypted connection. See [session hijacking @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking). Are there any countermeasures to handle this?

Comment: @Palec my main point was that the potential damage from a hijacked session on Stack Overflow is very small, compared to a GMail account. But full SSL support is planned now: [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116782)

Comment: @Pëkka Just reading through that. I noticed that HTTPS works, but sometimes a HTTP link can be seen and it switches you to unencrypted connection. I noticed it in inbox. Met tip to use HTTPS Everywhere browser extension and it seems really interesting.