# Wildcard SSL Cert producing error on Facebook.Stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-deferred

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Found a wildcard error with Facebook.stackoverflow.com, thought you should know!

[image: facebook.stackoverflow.com error HTTPS]

Comment: The same message appears (for me) for https://stackoverflow.com and https://www.stackoverflow.com but proceeding just goes to the non https address anyway

Comment: Where did we link you to `https://`? :)

Comment: @NickCraver checking my history, I'll need to re-open a couple tabs ;) one sec....

Comment: @NickCraver the link was a Facebook forward, I can't find/remember origin: http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.stackoverflow.com%2F&h=_AQHstJkq

Comment: @NickCraver this actually might be coming directly from a Facebook documentation page now that I think about it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL on Stack Overflow is not supported at this time.

Comment: Agreed, not sure where it came from but it was a Facebook forward link: http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.stackoverflow.com%2F&h=_AQHstJkq

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/378460688836379 This is where the link came from.