# Google Chrome warning of an SSL problem with Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, 500-server-error, ssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites)

When I go to Stack Overflow from Chrome, I get this warning:

[image: Chrome's "This is probably not the site you are looking for!" error]

I just installed Chrome on Mint 12. Not sure if this is only happening on my machine.

Comment: I don't know if you care, but your name is visible in your taskbar. (Well, _someone_'s name is, at least.)

Comment: See [my explanation on another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116798/141525).

Comment: @PopularDemand I don't care about it brother :D but thanks for notifying me, i hadn't notice it, yeah but whatever, i have a real name in real life :D

Comment: The SSL cert is for stackexchange.com.  You can pretty much use any sites SSL cert, but if the domain on the cert doesn't match yours, it'll give you this kind of warning in any browser.  Supporting SSL isn't high on the list of things to be done, apparently.