# Why am I getting a security warning from Chrome browser when navigating to StackOverflow?

Tags: support, security

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites) 
>   [Google Chrome warning of an SSL problem with Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121960/google-chrome-warning-of-an-ssl-problem-with-stack-overflow)

I tried to navigate to this Stack Overflow answer [Hash algorithms - Fastest implementations | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5459034/1114256) from a website that was not part of Stack Exchange. The Google Chrome browser on Windows 7 returned the following:

[image: Screen capture 21 Oct 2012 approx 3:00 Arizona Time]

I am feeling some concern.

- In my haste, I neglected to obscure all browser my bookmarks. Yes, I am an active [Pinterest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinterest) user.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not use SSL.

Comment: You should alert the source of the link and have him put proper link instead. (using `http://` rather than `https://`)

Comment: Well, `https://www.stackoverflow.com` is simply a broken link. In my opinion it's no different than http://www.stackoverflaw.com or any other wrong/broken link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSL certificate is valid for stackexchange.com, and *.stackexchange.com, while you are visiting stackoverflow.com. That is the reason you are getting that error.

Firefox gives me a similar error. These are the details about the error:

> stackoverflow.com uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for the following names:
>     *.stackexchange.com , stackexchange.com

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why doesn't this happen with other StackExchange sites from non SE sites e.g. Security StackExchange, when I navigate here https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20461/12057 with the https?

Comment: "The SSL certificate is valid for stackexchange.com, and *.stackexchange.com", @Feral

Comment: Because they are `*.stackexchange.com` domains.

Comment: Oh, sigh, sorry! I forgot that stackoverflow has its own domain, that the others are subdomains. And so does SuperUser (have its own domain)! Sorry!

Comment: So I'd have the same problem with both SuperUser and ServerFault, yes?

Comment: @FeralOink I get the same error for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: @FeralOink The question you linked explains exactly why they are not going to use secure connections on the trilogy sites. As the status is [meta-tag:status-deferred], there is the hope they can implement it in the future, but it is not something they can do in the next months.