# Stack Overflow's auto-update doesn't work with Opera

Tags: support, opera, web-sockets

When I view a question on Stack Overflow, normally I see all vote, comment, and edit activity 'live', without needing to refresh the page.

I recently installed Opera, and noticed that this doesn't work. I don't see any updates unless I refresh.

I think Stack Overflow uses WebSockets, right? Opera has WebSockets disabled by default, but enabling them didn't fix it. I tested with http://websocketstest.com/ and it told me WebSockets might work for me. The only thing it showed a problem with was the Port 443, SSL part, where nothing worked.

I'm running Opera 12.02 on Windows 7.

How can I fix this? Is there a configuration setting in Opera I can set? Or is this a limitation of Stack Overflow?

Comment: [SSL isn't supposed to work.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116782).

Comment: @animuson What does that mean? That SO doesn't use SSL for WebSockets?

Comment: They don't use SSL in general. I'm just pointing it out since you mentioned it. :)

Comment: You could just use another browser.

Comment: @senilesage I could, but I like Opera too much.

Comment: Any news on this one?

Comment: @Baz Nope, nothing that I know of.

Comment: @KendallFrey It's a shame. Really like Opera and can't really use it with SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this issue has been fixed. I now see updates in Opera.