# The Stack Exchange SSL certificate does not cover Ask Ubuntu or Math Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, ssl, askubuntu

It looks like HTTPS recently went live on mSO, and so I went looking at the shiny new SSL certificate.

Unfortunately, I discovered that it seems to cover all the Stack Exchange sites except for [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).

I received a certificate with serial number `09:1C:92:F2:8A:14:08:58:EE:AA:50:16:B9:72:89:FE`.

The list of subject alternate names I saw in the certificate was:

```
Not Critical
DNS Name: *.stackexchange.com
DNS Name: stackexchange.com
DNS Name: meta.stackexchange.com
DNS Name: *.meta.stackexchange.com
DNS Name: *.stackoverflow.com
DNS Name: stackoverflow.com
DNS Name: serverfault.com
DNS Name: stackauth.com
DNS Name: sstatic.net
DNS Name: meta.serverfault.com
DNS Name: superuser.com
DNS Name: meta.superuser.com
DNS Name: stackapps.com
DNS Name: openid.stackauth.com
```

Will Ask Ubuntu also get HTTPS? Is this just a small oversight?

Comment: Complete HTTPS support across Stack Exchange [is an ongoing project](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites). All sites will eventually be supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) is covered by a certificate with serial number `05:F4:1E:16:6E:2F:40:17:1E:F6:E4:33:11:FF:03:D0` and subject alternate names:

```
Not Critical
DNS Name: stackexchange.com
DNS Name: askubuntu.com
DNS Name: meta.askubuntu.com
DNS Name: answers.onstartups.com
DNS Name: meta.answers.onstartups.com
DNS Name: careers.joelonsoftware.com
DNS Name: discuss.area51.stackexchange.com
DNS Name: mathoverflow.net
DNS Name: meta.mathoverflow.net
```

Comment: That looks like a completely different certificate.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yep.

Answer (score 0):

Ask Ubuntu is now on the main certificate as part of the overall HTTP project, you can see the details here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=askubuntu.com