# SSL Errors on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, ssl

I noticed beginning today that I'm receiving `ssl_error_illegal_parameter_alert` on various stack exchange sites. I've encountered the error so far on Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, and Superuser. The error itself doesn't appear to occur on the *.stackexchange.com sites, but I can't guarantee that as I've not spent much time trying to reproduce it there. I've never had problems with Stack Exchange before this.

For more info, I'm currently running *Firefox Nightly 29.0a1* with *HTTPS Everywhere*, *Ghostery*, and *NoScript*.

The actual error page:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: There are reports about this happening if you have Kaspersky AV installed with Web Control enabled, if that's applicable to your situation. SSL isn't officially supported yet on the Stack Exchange network, so you might want to [disable the HTTPS Everywhere rule](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214968/cant-login-with-stack-exchange-openid-when-https-everywhere-plugin-is-active) for as a workaround for the time being, but this is presumably a client-side issue. I don't have a nightly Firefox build to test with, but I can't repro in my environment.

Comment: There's a thread on Mozilla support about this too - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/980582 it does appear to be Kaspersky.

Comment: @TimStone Would appear to be a Kaspersky problem after all. My company uses Kaspersky Endpoint Security 8. Oddly enough, I thought I'd already disabled it entirely on my system, but *Web Control* was still enabled. Thanks. If you'd like to add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [reports about this happening](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/980582) in Firefox if you have Kaspersky AV installed with Web Control enabled. Other antivirus software may also have similar problems when integrating with new/unstable browser builds, so that's worth looking into.

You can also [disable the HTTPS Everywhere rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214968/cant-login-with-stack-exchange-openid-when-https-everywhere-plugin-is-active) as a workaround for the time being, because the Stack Exchange network doesn't officially support SSL anyway (and as a result you get a lot of mixed content, and some things like authentication and closing as duplicate don't work correctly).