# Meta SE's have SSL errors making it impossible to login

Tags: bug, ssl

This is a quite serious bug, rendering all meta SE's useless (in setups similar to mine). I noticed this problem a few days ago and it's still here.

I tested this on meta.bitcoin.SE and meta.math.SE using the latest stable Chrome on Mac.

When doing to the meta page using https, you get following warning:

[image]

When proceeding to the https-version, it's possible to login, but not to post questions. For some reason I get a CAPTCHA that fails to load.

When proceeding to the http-version. I log in and the page after the login page shows that I'm logged in, but clicking any link will make me no longer logged in.

If you read this question, it means that it is possible to use the meta.SO, so probably the problem is with meta.XX.SE being a sub-subdomain.

Comment: I saw this somewhere - the problem is you can't get certificates for `meta.*.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: You can get individual ones for `*.XX.SE`. Is it industry standard that `x.x.domain.com` is not considered matching `*.domain.com`?

Comment: No, the problem is that wildcards only work in the leftmost position, and the alternative is listing each site separately (at 20 or so domains per cert, I can hear the bank accounts screaming).

Comment: If `x.x.domain` would just be considered covered by `*.domain`, there would be no problem. Either way, this has to be fixed because this way, the meta's are not usable. I don't know how they did it before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't login with Stack Exchange OpenID when HTTPS-Everywhere plugin is active - apparent protocol mismatch](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214968/cant-login-with-stack-exchange-openid-when-https-everywhere-plugin-is-active)

Comment: HTTPS *isn't* actively supported, true, but I don't think that's a duplicate @TimStone. Same underlying problem (which the tag [[meta-tag:ssl]] covers), very different symptoms (different enough to warrant a different question).

Comment: @michaelb958 The underlying problem is HTTPS Everywhere, since without it the OP would have nothing to report.

Comment: So basically, HTTPS is not supported for sub-subdomains, which is basically all meta's?

Comment: You may want to read the blog post [Stackoverflow.com: the road to SSL](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) by Nick Craver - he explains the certificate issue there. As others have commented, we can't get a `meta.*.stackexchange.com` cert or a `*.*.stackexchange.com` cert. Not because the latter is **technically** impossible, but because no CA will issue one (years ago someone abused such a certificate and now everyone else has to suffer...).