# Chat link in top bar isn't site-specific when using HTTPS

Tags: bug, chat, top-bar, ssl

Since the redesign of the top bar, it appears the chat room link next to a site no longer goes to that site's chats.  For instance, this link:

[image: physics chat link]

should go to something like https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=people&host=physics.stackexchange.com, but it just goes to https://chat.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: It still works for you though, right? I mean, following that link just shows you the physics chat rooms? Because that's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @Shog9: No. No matter which site I click from, the link goes to http://chat.stackexchange.com/, which shows all the chat rooms for all the sites, listed by most active, starting with Motor Vehicle Maintenance, Mathematics, Arqade, Raspberry Pi, etc.

Comment: @Shog9: Aha.  It works with [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) disabled, but not when enabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't login with Stack Exchange OpenID when HTTPS-Everywhere plugin is active - apparent protocol mismatch](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214968/cant-login-with-stack-exchange-openid-when-https-everywhere-plugin-is-active)

Comment: Same thing with regular `http` these days. @Shog9 should this be fixed, should I open a new post?

Comment: Open a new bug, @Raphael - be sure to include the browser and OS you're using.

Comment: @Shog9 [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248382/chat-link-in-top-bar-is-not-site-specific), thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the chat.stackexchange.com is trying to do some magic [referrer sniffing](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) to detect the site you're coming from.  Alas, this doesn't work if you were using HTTPS, since [browsers don't send referrer info when following an HTTP link from an HTTPS page](//tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-15.1.3).

Using a [protocol-relative link to chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just), so that chat would also be loaded over HTTPS, would be the optimal solution.  Unfortunately, [SE chat still breaks horribly over HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites/222350#222350), so that's not practical at the moment.

An alternative work-around is to inject the missing parameters back into the link on pages loaded over HTTPS, e.g. like this:

```javascript
if ('https:' != location.protocol) return;
$('.siteSwitcher-dialog a[href="http://chat.stackexchange.com"]').attr(
    'href', 'http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=' +
        location.hostname.replace(/(^|\.)meta\./, '')
);
```

Ps. While waiting for a proper fix, I have included this workaround in [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.12.

Comment: For me, neither the original "magic" nor your fix work with regular http.

Comment: Update: SE chat nowadays does work over HTTPS (yay!),  so this specific fix is no longer necessary; simply [fixing the chat links to use HTTPS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223725) is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

So what's the difference? The first link just has a query string attached. The second one doesn't. The server might not need that query string anymore. So they removed it.

The site is the same, you can see for the URL: https://chat.stackexchange.com there you can go to the site itself.

FYI, even with the query string attached, it won't go to the specific site chat.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I updated the link