# Can't log into chat with the "HTTPS Everywhere" plugin

Tags: bug, chat, login, ssl

I know that HTTPS isn't officially supported, but it works well enough for me on StackExchange most of the time.

Recently something changed with chat so that I can't login to it with the HTTPS Everywhere plugin (in Firefox) enabled.

My use case:

- I'm on [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) (using HTTPS)
- From the "StackExchange" menu I select "chat" to get to the Pro Webmasters chat rooms
- I go to chat (also on HTTPS), but it is a list of chat rooms that are not specific to the webmaster site.  I also notice that I'm not logged in.
- I click the "login" link and I get get the message `Please log in to any StackExchange site first, or log in via StackExchange.com.`
- Firefox pops up the security warning: `Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party. Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?` (I hit "Continue")
- The chat server gives me the error `No referer was present - this may be due to a browser setting`

Up until a week or two ago I was able to access chat even when using the HTTPS Everywhere plugin.  Something changed recently.

Comment: HTTPS is not officially supported yet. I would suspect that until all the details are worked out, any change behind the scenes could break it.

Comment: There are a few similar questions. It isn't supported. Don't do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't login with Stack Exchange OpenID when HTTPS-Everywhere plugin is active - apparent protocol mismatch](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214968/cant-login-with-stack-exchange-openid-when-https-everywhere-plugin-is-active)

Comment: I don't believe that is a duplicate.   A workaround was put in for that bug.   That bug was for the unix site, not for chat.  The error messages are different.

Comment: I have this same problem; hope it gets fixed, as I like https.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a side-effect of the fact that [the chat link is not protocol-relative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223725/all-internal-links-on-stack-exchange-sites-should-be-protocol-relative), causing Firefox not to send a Referer (sic) header when it's clicked, even though HTTPS Everywhere actually rewrites the request to use HTTPS.

As a work-around, consider installing [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223725/all-internal-links-on-stack-exchange-sites-should-be-protocol-relative) user script, which rewrites such links to use HTTPS *before* you click them, allowing the correct Referer header to be sent.

BTW, you might also consider [reporting this as a bug in HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/development).  Even if it's not possible for the extension to pass the Referer header along, it might be possible to [rewrite the chat links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226343/chat-link-in-top-bar-isnt-site-specific-when-using-https) to contain this information in the URL itself using the following syntax:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=webmasters.stackexchange.com

However, this would presumably require some way for the HTTPS Everywhere ruleset to embed parts of the referring page's URL into the rewritten URL; I don't know if such a feature exists yet, or how difficult it would be to develop.