# Can't enter the Tavern on the Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

When I go to [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), the room states that I didn't log in.

[image]

When I click "log in", the page merely refreshes, still stating that I didn't log in.

When I try to visit [chat.meta.SE](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com), I get this:

[image: A cat is workin on mah problemz]

Same thing happens with [Low Quality Posts HQ](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/773/low-quality-posts-hq).

What's going on here? Do I have to enter the Tavern with something else than Chrome 51.0.2704.106/[Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge) 25.10586.0.0 running on Windows 10 x64?

Also, I don't use HTTPS Everywhere or a similar extension forcing sites to use HTTPS.

Comment: Can't repro over here

Comment: Can't repro in FireFox / Win10

Comment: If you're trying to access the chat using https, or using HTTPS Everywhere, or a similar plugin/extension forcing https, it's dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243419/cant-log-into-chat-with-the-https-everywhere-plugin

Comment: What is your OpenID provider? (e.g. Google, Facebook, Stack Exchange?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Stack Exchange

Comment: OK, something broke in your [chat profile](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/329351), I get error trying to view it. SE dev will have to reset your profile, then you should be able to use chat again.

Comment: Did you go through account merge at some point, perhaps? (or deleted account that was restored)

Comment: @ShadowWizard No.

Comment: OK, it gets weirder. Looks like your actual chat profile is this: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/328256/dorukayhan but it's not synchronised with this account of yours but rather with a deleted account. All in all, looks like there was a merge, maybe automatic that you weren't even aware of.

Comment: @dorukayhan Try again.

Comment: No merge. Just a self-initiated profile deletion, @ShadowWizard.

Comment: @AdamLear Yay! It works now!

Comment: @Adam I see. I noticed bunch of old bug reports here about this same  issue, none of them resolved. Latest of those is about year ago. Any point trying the same method on them? Edit: ignore, none of the chat profiles of those is missing, probably something else. (or it has been resolved by now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to make sure the question doesn't become useless if the comments below it ever get deleted, this is what was going on:

Before achieving the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/329351) and being able to make posts on Meta.SE (posting on MSE required 2 reputation back then), I created and [deleted my account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281378/cant-enter-the-tavern-on-the-meta#comment914103_281378) more than once. This spawned dangling deleted accounts on [MSE chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com), and one of these deleted accounts became associated with the MSE account I created after (finally) hitting 200 rep on Stack Overflow, thus preventing me from entering any meta chatroom such as [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and [Low Quality Posts HQ](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/773/low-quality-posts-hq).

Any user who deleted his/her MSE account at least once is prone to this weird bug.

Comment: FWIW, we're about to fix this. User deletions on Q&A sites will start cleaning up appropriately after themselves in chat... hopefully this week, but failing that next week. (Failing *that*, in 6-8 weeks. ;))

Comment: @Adam so maybe remove the completed tag here, and put it back (with proper answer) only when this fix is applied? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard No. This specific report is resolved.