# Can't login to *http* meta.startups even though I have an account

Tags: bug, ssl

I have a [login on startups.SE](https://startups.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3640/dan-dascalescu) but when I click the login link, the page just re-loads and I remain logged out.

The login link points to https://startups.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fmeta.startups.stackexchange.com%2fusers%2f3640%2fdan-dascalescu

I suspect this is caused by HTTPS Everywhere, even though I've disabled its function for SE sites. If I go to https://startups.meta.stackexchange.com/, I showed up as login, though with a cert problem:

[image]

Comment: Is this using work internet or your own?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome from my own ISP, without restrictions. Actually this seems like a particular case of [Can't login with Stack Exchange OpenID when HTTPS-Everywhere plugin is active - apparent protocol mismatch](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214968/cant-login-with-stack-exchange-openid-when-https-everywhere-plugin-is-active)

Comment: ...who downvotes the site self-evaluation?