# Custom avatars are fetched using http instead of https

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, profile-picture, ssl

Stack Overflow [seems](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) to work through [HTTPS connection](https://stackoverflow.com/), but the custom avatars (uploaded files, not those from gravatar) are even then fetched from https://i.stack.imgur.com/ using standard [http](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV8LZ.png) [connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMsOn.jpg) (which generates warning in browsers and is not a very good practice). As those images are also available [through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV8LZ.png) [HTTPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMsOn.jpg) it could be just a service misconfiguration.

Is there a technical (or any other) reason why they couldn't be fetched using HTTPS?

Comment: Screenshot for confirmation (I use a custom avatar): http://i.stack.imgur.com/M4opG.png

Comment: Looks like they just store the absolute URL of the picture in the database, see that gravatar based pictures always use https even when browsing the non secure site.

Comment: SSL support is planned/in progress, and still not officially supported. This is one of the items on our TODO list.

Comment: @m0sa so isn't this a dupe of [that one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116782/152859)? (when it will be completed, this one will too)

Comment: @ShadowWizard it's a part of it, I guess we might as well close it as a dupe..

Comment: Added my meager vote. :)

Comment: @M0sa, I have seen that issue, but it is about access through SSL to Stack Exchange sites in general. There are two issues mentioned, the second one may be in fact the same, but there are no details and it is not known what content it is about. My question/report is about a concrete content - uploaded profile pictures and as they are already available also through HTTPS it could a misconfiguration or just an overlook which possibly could be easily fixed (it is not the same as the need to make some external resources available via HTTPS when they are served only via HTTP).