# Untrusted connection when visiting per-site meta over SSL

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, ssl

Steps to reproduce:

- In Firefox (with [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere)), visit a non-trilogy Stack Exchange site (for example, http://movies.stackexchange.com)
- Get redirected to the HTTPS version
- Click on meta link (for example, https://meta.movies.stackexchange.com)

What should happen:

- Meta site opens

What happens instead:

- "This Connection is Untrusted" message appears:

> meta.movies.stackexchange.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.stackexchange.com, stackexchange.com, meta.stackexchange.com, *.meta.stackexchange.com, *.stackoverflow.com, stackoverflow.com, serverfault.com, stackauth.com, sstatic.net, meta.serverfault.com, superuser.com, meta.superuser.com, stackapps.com, openid.stackauth.com (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

Notes:

- It also happens if you visit http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com instead (you get redirected to HTTPS and the error occurs)
- Another random example, https://meta.math.stackexchange.com
- Trilogy metas work, [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour) works (but https://www.askubuntu.com doesn't - I am not sure what gave me that link)
- Replacing URL with https://*.meta.stackexchange doesn't work

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Image description]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this on standard settings on firefox 26.0. I'll have a play with security settings

Comment: Ah, I wasn't automatically redirected. By manually entering [https://movies.stackexchange.com/](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) I was able to get this

Comment: Related: [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Do you have the HTTPS Everywhere addon installed? It seems they added some rulesets about SSL support on Stack Exchange without first consulting Stack Exchange, and thereby broke quite a lot of stuff.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen ah, yes, I do - so I guess it isn't a SE bug then

Comment: @d3vid nope, not a bug, more of a "known issue that they're steadily working on"

Comment: @Flyk "steadily working on" isn't quite right. Over two years later, nothing has been done. I'll be really really surprised if it will be ever done. It's just too big a project for SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [Nick Craver's blog post](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) about getting Stack Exchange onto SSL, it is currently impossible for them to get SSL working on the meta sites, because wildcard certs of the form 'meta.*.stackexchange.com' won't work.

Nick provided more info in [this post on Arqade meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8061/ssl-error-on-meta); the plan is to change the domains to make it work. Until then, metas don't support SSL. In fact, none of the sites do, officially.

Comment: I tried to read the post on meta but got a This Connection is Untrusted error - filed a bug here: [Untrusted connection when visiting per-site meta over SSL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216384) ;D