# Per-site metas broken when using HTTPS

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, ssl, cdn, cloudflare

I just noticed that trying to visit one of the per-site metas using HTTPS will (after confirming the security exception due to the [limitations of SSL wildcard certificates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216384/untrusted-connection-when-visiting-meta-stack-exchange-sites)) give a 403 error:

[image: Screenshot]

Yes, I know that [HTTPS is not officially supported on SE (yet)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites).  But the per-site metas *used to* work over HTTPS, so this is a regression.

I did some extra testing, and it appears that this error shows up *only* for the per-site metas with a four-part hostname of the form `meta.sitename.stackexchange.com`.  That is, the following meta sites with custom domains work fine over HTTPS:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com
- https://meta.superuser.com
- https://meta.serverfault.com
- https://meta.askubuntu.com
- https://meta.mathoverflow.net

but any other per-site metas, (like, say, https://meta.math.stackexchange.com) are broken.

From the error message, I suspect this regression has something to do with the use of the CloudFlare CDN.  Perhaps something needs to be (re)configured in SE's CloudFlare settings to make this work again?

Comment: It seems that bug report has come down to the same as this...