# i.stack.imgur.com has an expired SSL certificate

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

The SSL certificate for StackExchange's Imgur image host seems to have expired today. Going to https://i.stack.imgur.com/ yields this page in Chrome:

[image]

(posted on regular Imgur, for obvious reasons)

Here's a picture of the certificate details:

[image]

As the images show, the SSL certificate expired today. This is causing problems throughout all SE sites, including chat.

On the Q&A sites, load times have increased significantly (although I'm not sure how closely connected that is to the expired SSL), and most images in questions and answers won't load:

[image]

In chat, since most people use Stack Imgur to host their avatars, it's a disaster, as there are almost no images that can be loaded:

[image]

Sorry again if this is off-topic, but I wanted to announce it/ask for it to be fixed if that's possible on the SE side.

**Edit**: Back up! Thanks SE and Imgur for getting this resolved so quickly.

Comment: They renewed it only for 12 days: https://i.stack.imgur.com/572ND.png so prepare for another bug report in November 10th. Great way to make lots of reputation! /cc @Geoff

Comment: @ShadowWizard that looks like a different certificate. Issued in 2013. Guess we'll see.

Comment: @Sha Zac is correct: they didn't renew the cert, just swapped it for an existing still-valid cert. One hopes they'll get a new cert entirely before this one expires.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I can't imagine that being too difficult, although this one was only valid for a year and was allowed to expire. Guess we'll see.

Comment: We'll see indeed, guess imgur try to save money, or just being too lazy. In 12 days we'll know better. /cc @ArtOfCode.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I personally don't see the point of having HTTPS in the first place, but then again I'm not a security expert.

Comment: @Zacharee1 part of the overall https support for Stack Exchange. If someone browse https://meta.stackexchange.com and the images are http only (not https) it will cause warning to appear, or even the images to not show, depends on the browser settings.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I thought full HTTPS for SE was a long way off. Is this just future proofing?

Comment: The reason it is long way off is the meta sites, as far as I know. Supporting https to meta sites under stackexchange.com domain requires changing the whole system and use totally different sub domains.

Comment: This is all explained in [this blog post](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) by Nick Craver and the per site meta issue is reported and explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216384/untrusted-connection-when-visiting-per-site-meta-over-ssl).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We have contacted imgur and they are fixing this as we speak.

Thanks for the report.

Comment: And it's back already. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I have the same problem now with one of my providers: `Issued by: allot.com`, signed by an untrusted user.