# Why does the SSL cert cover meta specifically?

Tags: discussion, ssl

According to [Qualy’s SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=meta.stackoverflow.com), this site’s SSL cert is for `*.stackexchange.com`, with the alternative names,

> *.stackexchange.com stackexchange.com meta.stackexchange.com *.meta.stackexchange.com *.stackoverflow.com stackoverflow.com serverfault.com stackauth.com sstatic.net meta.serverfault.com superuser.com meta.superuser.com stackapps.com openid.stackauth.com

Wow, that’s a lot of alternative names.

You may notice some overlap. One name is `meta.stackexchange.com` and another is `*.stackexchange.com`. There doesn’t seem to be any reason to have a specific cert for meta. Is there?

Comment: Not sure if [this answers your question but it gives some high level design insights](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/)

Comment: Unless, *maybe*, `meta.stackexchange.com` is needed to also allow for `*.meta.stackexchange.com` (but I doubt that)?

Comment: @Arjan: Not `*.meta.stackexchange.com`, but `meta.*.stackexchange.com`.  Programmers' meta site is `meta.programmers.stackexchange.com`

Comment: This is true, @Robert, but no `meta.*.stackexchange.com` certificate exists (nor would it be accepted if it did, as the link in rene's comment makes clear), however, a `*.meta.stackexchange.com` cert *does* exist, for whatever reason.