# Make all i.stack.imgur.com links protocol-relative

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, ssl

Stack Overflow has HTTPS in some places! However, this breaks most existing image links. Could those be made protocol-relative, or react to the requesting protocol, or just always use HTTPS?

The same applies to `.sponsor-tag-img`.

Comment: I don't think always using HTTPS would be a good choice, even if it only applied to imgur links.  This would increase the latency of the image download, which could have a significant impact on mobile clients, and often have no benefit.  Protocol-relative on a web-page would be the way to go.

Comment: Also, if the same image URL information is used to generate payloads for the Stack Exchange iOS/Android apps, the image should almost always be HTTP since mixed protocols isn't an issue there.

Comment: @AaronBrager: Mixed protocols aren’t disallowed for fun. It’s a security (well, privacy) problem. Yes, even globally-accessible images without cookies.

Comment: Right, but on web non-private images are commonly sent via HTTPS to avoid mixed protocol errors.  My point was simply: *if* the images are not private, it's wasteful to use HTTPS to transmit them.

Comment: [Nick does discuss this in his blog post on bringing SE to HTTPS](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/): `Inline Images: we can’t include insecure content on the page…so that means turning our images to SSL when i.stack.imgur.com is ready.  For other domains images are embedded from we have to turn them into links, or solve via another approach.`

Comment: @hichris123: Yes, i.stack.imgur.com has supported HTTPS for a while.

Comment: Investigating [a different SSL issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226561/188688), I noticed that gravatars cause mixed content messages to the console as well. Since Gravatar [does support HTTPS](https://secure.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/#secure-images), fixing both issues at the same time should be feasible.

Comment: If rewriting image URLs in posts is too much work, could we at least get this fixed for user avatars uploaded to i.stack.imgur.com?  Gravatar images already seem to be using protocol-relative URLs, so it seems like at least some similar code must already be in place.

Comment: @Oded almost two years later, is this still planned?

Comment: I have no idea what the status of this is, but you could always use Camo Proxy Server.

Comment: @DavidB: They don’t even need to do that for the internal i.stack images.

Comment: @Ryan: No they don't. To be completely honest I don't know much of anything about Camo. I have never used it. I just know what it is and what purpose it serves.

Comment: @AaronBrager That's why protocol-relative URLs are such a good fit for this; for those browsing over HTTP for one reason or another, they fetch the images over HTTP, but for those who browse over HTTPS, the images (or whatever other resource is being requested) are fetched over HTTPS. Especially now that Stack Exchange (sans site-specific metas) is mostly usable over HTTPS only, that at least puts the user in control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly as requested, but all image embeds are `https://` now, as part of deploying HTTPS across the network. This causes fetching over HTTP/2 and results in a faster experience.

Answer (score 2):

The just released [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.14 includes a client-side work-around for this issue.

Ideally, such a work-around would intercept any requests for image files over HTTP and rewrite them to use HTTPS.  However, while this is possible for a browser extension like [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/), I'm not aware of any cross-browser way to do it with a simple user script like SOUP.

Instead, the way this work-around works is by detecting images that:

1. have failed to load,
2. have a `http:` URL on a page loaded over `https:`, and
3. are on a domain known to support HTTPS simply by changing the protocol in the URL.

Notably, condition #1 means that this work-around *only* applies if your browser is configured to block insecure images on secure pages.  For Firefox, this setting is available on the `about:config` page as `security.mixed_content.block_display_content`.  I'm not currently aware of any way to change this setting for other browsers.

This also means that **you'll still get mixed-content errors** in your browser error log; the work-around just reloads the images over HTTPS *after* they've failed to load over insecure HTTP.

Also, while SOUP does try to re-run the work-around code whenever new content is injected via AJAX or otherwise modified, it's possible that there may be some remaining cases where dynamically loaded images are not fixed properly.  If you find any, please let me know.

The domains for which the work-around is enabled currently include:

- **imgur.com** (including stack.imgur.com), used for user-uploaded images using the SE editor's upload tool, as well as for user avatars uploaded via SE;
- **gravatar.com**, used for global user avatars (actually, gravatar images seem to be already loaded over HTTPS anyway, but I've included it just in case);
- **facebook.com**, used for avatars for users logging in via Facebook;
- **wikimedia.org** (including upload.wikimedia.org), a popular source of freely licensed images;
- **sstatic.net**, used for some SE interface graphics, such as site icons (mostly loaded over HTTPS already, but IIRC I found some broken ones when I tested this); and
- **stackexchange.com** and all other Stack Exchange sites (stackoverflow.com, superuser.com, serverfault.com, stackapps.com, askubuntu.com, mathoverflow.net), used e.g. for user flair images.

Some notable examples of domains to which the workaround is *not* applied include chart.apis.google.com ([Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/), does not seem to support HTTPS) and imageshack.us ([could be supported](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/atlas/domains/imageshack.us.html), but would require more complex URL mangling than just changing the protocol).

---

Just in case you're curious, here's the whole code, as included in SOUP v1.20.0:

```javascript
if ( 'https:' != location.protocol ) return;
var urlRegex = /^http:\/\/(([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*((imgur|gravatar|facebook)\.com|wikimedia\.org|sstatic\.net|(stack(exchange|overflow|apps)|superuser|serverfault|askubuntu)\.com|mathoverflow\.net))\//i;
var fixImages = function (target) {
    $(target).find('img[src^="http://"]').each( function () {
        if ( ! urlRegex.test( this.src ) ) return;
        if ( ! this.complete || this.naturalWidth > 0 ) return;
        var newUrl = this.src.replace( urlRegex, 'https://$1/' );
        SOUP.log( 'soup mse221304 fixing img ' + this.src + ' -> ' + newUrl );
        this.src = newUrl;
    } );
};
SOUP.addContentFilter( fixImages, 'HTTPS image fix' );
$(document).on( 'mouseenter', '#user-menu', function () {
    SOUP.try( 'HTTPS image fix', fixImages, [this] );
} );
```

Comment: Why don’t you just make it replace all `http:` images, errored or not? (I do have everything configured to block passive mixed content, so it shouldn’t make any difference, but might prevent warnings.)

Comment: @minitech: Because there's not much point -- the browser has already started to load the image before the script has a chance to kick in, so the insecure request has already been made (and may well have already completed). At that point, if the request wasn't blocked, reloading the image over HTTPS would be just closing the stable door after the horse has bolted. It would also waste bandwidth for users with insecure image loading enabled, since every image would be requested twice, first over HTTP and then over HTTPS.

Comment: https://chart.apis.google.com/ works now.