# Updating all links to user avatars to use HTTPS

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-picture, ssl

I've recently been firing pull requests at Stack Exchange's [new blog on github](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog) fixing mixed content warnings, and found that HTTPS is pretty well supported on `i.stack.imgur.com`, which is where user-uploaded profiles are.

I'm proposing that a dev goes through the databases for all Stack Exchange sites, and changes all of the `[Users].[ProfileImageUrl]` fields for all users to do the following changes:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com  -> https://i.stack.imgur.com
http://graph.facebook.com -> https://graph.facebook.com
http://www.gravatar.com   -> https://www.gravatar.com
```

See [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/337368/435556/select-all-profile-images-that-use-plain-http) for more on plain avatar URLS.

Stackoverflow only:

```
https://lh3.googleu... -> 62590
https://i.stack.img... -> 4
https://lh4.googleu... -> 58269
https://www.gravata... -> 1491834
https://lh5.googleu... -> 58487
https://lh6.googleu... -> 58764
//i.stack.imgur.com... -> 4

-- Here onwards
http://graph.facebo... -> 394107
http://i.stack.imgu... -> 274856
http://www.gravatar... -> 2685
```

This'd eliminate 90% of the mixed content warnings on Stack Exchange over HTTPS.

Script to run to fix this, for brevity:

```sql
update [Users] set [ProfileImageUrl] = Replace([ProfileImageUrl], '/http:/', '/https:/');
```

Normally I'd run on each domain specifically, but every single avatar host supported by Stack Exchange supports HTTPS.

Comment: Not a duplicate; it's a feature request with an actual solution, unlike every other question about https.

Comment: Yes a duplicate. Both are feature requests asking for the exact same thing.

Comment: No, not a single one says *how* to do it. I made this post so I could point a dev to it directly.

Comment: Besides, the claimed dupe is a dupe itself of a very generic question that doesn't answer this one in any meaningful way

Comment: Another related generic feature-req: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221304/make-all-i-stack-imgur-com-links-protocol-relative

Comment: This is a dupe, and the duped questions have been marked "status-planned" by a mod/Stack staff, so we're better of concentrating on those rather than just have another one asking for the same thing. As for your specific proposal, you should consider adding the details from your question here to the open dupe, if you feel it adds more to the discussions.

Comment: @James I made this post to link it to a dev in chat. The meta post was so it could actually be documented.

Comment: We have planned to make all avatar URLs protocol-relative. There's even someone assigned to it. It'll happen (shortly if all goes well).

Comment: @Thomas you forgot the magic term: 6-8 weeks.