# How is the roll-out of HTTPS images going?

Tags: support, images, ssl, imgur

Today I noticed (over on [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), reproduced here on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)) that when I upload pictures, the imgur links that are automatically inserted into the post now use `https://i.stack.imgur.com/` instead of `https://i.stack.imgur.com/` no matter whether or not I browse the site over HTTPS or HTTP.
This behavior was confirmed to me by at least one other person (note: neither of us is using [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/q/4486))

So my questions:

1. **Is this active network-wide for all users as of now?**
2. **If not, how are the plans on rolling it out?**

Anyways, thank you so much for finally making this change :)

Related reading (which is a partially weaker feature-request):
[*"Make all i.stack.imgur.com links protocol-relative"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221304/296259)