# Roadmap for HTTPS/SSL support

Tags: support, status-completed, ssl

Every once in a while, someone comes to Meta to report a bug about something not working and it turns out that person is visiting one of the network sites over HTTPS/SSL. The problem has been growing since browsers started to outright block mixed content instead of showing a warning.

The usual answer is that HTTPS is not yet fully supported, and the person should try again using HTTP. Sometimes things get fixed, improving the situation a bit.

Is there a roadmap for full support? Partial support has been there for [more than two years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites) now.

Is this actively being worked on? If not, what are the reasons to partially support it instead of disabling it completely to avoid these problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The switch to HTTPS is about to happen, as detailed in the [HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345012/https-its-time) post on MSO.

Comment: [Only on SO for now apparently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345012/https-its-time?noredirect=1#comment453940_345012)

Comment: @Cai Yeah, but from what I understand MSE should closely follow, and after that all other sites will be moved. Anyway, just posted an answer here to "resolve" the question and not leave any open ends.

Comment: Sure, just wasn't obvious (from the MSO post) that this wasn't being rolled out network wide right now.

Comment: See also (the coincidentally named) [Roadmap to HTTPS: serving and uploading HTTPS-images only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only) here on Meta SE.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, SSL support is actively being worked on, and will be completed once they can figure out how to account for all of the pitfalls associated with the transition. My (admittedly uninformed) understanding is that there's no hard timeline in place, just because it's difficult to gauge what it will take to tackle some of the issues.

You can view Nick's [original blog post about the subject](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/), and he's reportedly working on a new one where he'll detail what they've been working on to make sure that HTTPS connection times fall in line with standard HTTP ones. [From the looks of things](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/445736228541829120), this will include an interactive map that summarizes [the various data points](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/439790848935337984) they collected during testing.

Comment: Interesting links, thanks!

Comment: Is SEDE considered to be part of this? In other words, does SEDE needs updates to support HTTPS/SSL?

Comment: @rene I think I already made most of the updates - some resource urls in the database might need to be updated, but otherwise I think it's okay. I'll check to be sure though.

Comment: Ok, I asked because of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237481/firefox-ssl-warning-for-data-stackexchange-com)

Comment: [A related bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265918/accessing-per-site-metas-gives-403-forbidden-from-cloudflare-nginx).