# Firefox SSL warning for data.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, data-explorer, ssl

When visiting https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/200561, firefox tells me that not all parts of the page are secured.

Looking from source, f.ex. following things are not using https

```
IconUrl: 'http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/icon-16.png'
<img class="site-icon" src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/icon-16.png" alt="Meta Stack Overflow" />
<img src="http://sstatic.net/img/progress-dots.gif" alt="loading" /> Hold tight while we fetch your results
```

Also nearly all navigation links go to http site instead of https, transitioning user back to insecure connection.

Perhaps these could be addressed?

Comment: I assume the data explorer is part of the effort for introducing/supporting ssl network wide. It might though not be the highest priority

Comment: @rene not realy, SEDE is a standalone project maintained by private people (currently Tim Stone) and Stack Exchange only host it. So I don't think it's dupe, as SEDE might be fully SSL'ish long before the whole SE network.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's duplicate enough, I don't want to use up Nick's time to make those resource changes until HTTPS is supported. That said, I can fix the static (non-per-site) image references now.