# Why is meta.unix.stackexchange.com not recognizing me as logged in when unix.stackexchange.com is?

Tags: discussion, login, user-accounts, per-site-meta

I wanted to ask a question on Meta Unix & Linux (http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com).  I'm logged in to Unix & Linux (http://unix.stackexchange.com), and it's showing just over 700 rep for me.  I switched to Meta-U&L and (a) I'm not logged in and (b) pressing the 'login' button didn't seem to do anything useful.

Any idea what gives?

- Why do you have to login to the meta when you're already logged in to the main site?
- How does one login to a meta when the login button does nothing useful?  Which weird non-Stack Exchange site has to be granted what privileges to do what possibly (but probably not) abusive things to my browser?

I'm using Firefox 41.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan.  I do have AdBlock Pro, Ghostery and other extensions installed.

---

[chirlu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/224208/chirlu) [asks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267713/why-is-meta-unix-stackexchange-com-not-recognizing-me-as-logged-in-when-unix-sta?noredirect=1#comment868120_267713):

> Are you sure you are logged in on the non-https Unix.SE?

I was going to say "yes", but then I look and see that in fact I *am* connected to the secure `https://unix.stackexchange.com/` (I have HTTPS Everywhere as one of the other extensions).  So, apparently, I'm logged in on secure U&L but there isn't a secure Meta-U&L (or, at least, connecting to https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/ ends up at http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com, losing the 's').  When I connect to SO, I'm connected to the secure version; when I switch to MSO, that is also the secure version.  That seems as though it could easily be the source of the trouble.  It leaves some questions:

1. Why isn't there a secure Meta-U&L like there is a secure MSO?
2. Do I have to disable HTTPS Everywhere for U&L so that I can see Meta-u&L as myself, or is there something else I can do?

Comment: Are you sure you are logged in on the non-https Unix.SE?

Comment: @chirlu: Thanks for the question — it looks like your thinking is on the right track.  I've updated the question with some extra information. Any suggestions?

Comment: Given the additional information from @chirlu, it looks like [Can't login with Stack Exchange OpenID when HTTPS Everywhere plugin is active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214968/) — which dates from January 2014 — is still a problem even when using Google rather than Stack Exchange as the OpenID source.  The workaround in that question is to turn off HTTPS Everywhere for U&L (it now works via the icon in the tool-bar/search-bar rather than the Tools-->HTTPS Everywhere menu, but that has resolved my immediate problem), but why isn't there a working secure Meta-U&L?

Comment: For the first part, why there aren’t (working) secure per-site metas, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265918 (in short: would require a separate certificate for each _meta.site.stackexchange.com_; will be fixed by changing to _site.meta.stackexchange.com_). For the other part, I had some troubles myself a while ago, but it works now for me. Unfortunately I don’t know what I did to make it work (or what some other party such as SE did to make it work), so not very helpful I guess. :-/