# Connection is not private when viewing per site meta over HTTPS

Tags: support, per-site-meta, ssl

I discovered the problem on this thread: [If time-travellers always arrive naked how and what would they trade?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/if-time-travellers-always-arrive-naked-how-and-what-would-they-trade?noredirect=1#comment72751_27808)

In the comments, another user posted a link to another part of the site. I followed the link.

Here is the worrying message I got:

> Your connection is not private
>   Attackers might be trying to steal your information from meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

[image: Your connection is not private]

The link is:

> ```
> https://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/questions-about-single-individual-actions
> ```

What is happening? Is Stack Exchange compromised?

Comment: SSL is not supported yet, which is what happens if you visit the site with `https://` instead of `http://` (notice the **S**)

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266921/browser-trusted-tls-for-per-site-metas-again and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265918/meta-space-stackexchange-com-gives-403-forbidden-from-cloudflare-nginx/266711#266711

Comment: similarly also reported on [scifi meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4903/31524), as well as [codereview meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5172/37660) as well as some others probably

Comment: But presumably it worked for the poster who posted the link.

Comment: @JDługosz there is the option to add specific certificate exceptions to firefox...

Comment: So TLS *is* being used, but with a certificate of improper pedagree.  Or is the browser detecting redirection or whatever, that varies by browser?

Answer (score 4):

The detailed error Firfox gives me is

> The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.stackexchange.com, stackexchange.com, meta.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com, *.stackoverflow.com, stackauth.com, sstatic.net, *.sstatic.net, serverfault.com, meta.superuser.com, stackapps.com, openid.stackauth.com, *.meta.stackexchange.com, clc.serverfault.com, meta.serverfault.com, superuser.com

Note that `meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com` is not among the host names nor does it match any of the wildcards (recall that the `*` wildcard represents only one domain level!)

With a mild frown, I'd be willing to allow the security override in this case.