# Why do meta sites use fourth-level domains?

Tags: discussion, login, openid, ssl

This morning, I was seeing confusing behavior while trying to log in to http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com. Login methods were returning me to the same page, not logged in. I had to turn off HTTPS Everywhere, log in, and turn HTTPS Everywhere back on. Apparently, this is a [known problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234031/why-cant-i-log-in-to-meta-stackexchange-com-without-broken-ssl/234113#234113) related to the fact that meta sites other than SE, SO, SF, SU, and Ask Ubuntu do not support TLS. I assume this is because wildcards don't work on any element of a certificate's subject name but the first. This means Stack Exchange can buy a certificate that covers `stackoverflow.com` and `meta.stackoverflow.com`, similar for Super User, Server Fault, and Ask Ubuntu, and `*.stackexchange.com` for most topic sites, but not `meta.*.stackexchange.com`.

So why do meta sites have hostnames like `meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com` and not `worldbuilding-meta.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: Because they didn't foresee this particular problem when designing the first meta sites as HTTPS wasn't supported.

Comment: [Stackoverflow.com: the road to SSL](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) by Nick Craver.

Comment: Also, it may be that SE does not like hyphens in URL for historical reasons: http://s.tk/hyphen

Answer (score 8):

A simple fix would be make all the metas subdomains of this site.

```
workplace.meta.stackexchange.com
```

It still messes with the child cookies, but you shouldn't be giving children that many cookies anyway, and you already work around this issue in so many other places for login that it probably isn't that painful.

Then you just need another wildcard certificate:

```
*.meta.stackexchange.com
```

Done in one.

Simple and obvious to users.  In a way it makes a certain sense for structuring meta sites anyway.

Comment: /TheCount That's two!  Two people who don't like my idea - Ah! Ah! Ah!

Comment: Congratulations! This is what ended up happening.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Do I get a cookie?

Comment: Everybody correctly authenticated does. But you can get a secure cookie! :-)