# Stats for HTTPS usage across the network

Tags: support, statistics, ssl

Are there numbers available on how many users are using the (not officially supported, but [much desired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116782/183280)) HTTPS versions of the SE sites?

I'd like to see percentage values of HTTP vs HTTPS use, broken down into logged-in contributors vs visitors and per site.