# StackExchange certificate issued for CloudFlare, SuperUser certificate issued to CloudFlare's FQDN

Tags: support, ssl

Two issues with the certs:

- SuperUser certificate is issued to `CN: ssl4121.cloudflare.com`, not `superuser.com`, and shared with an unrelated site (https://wimdu.co.uk)
- StackExchange certificate is issued to `O: CloudFlare, Inc.`

I understand that both qualify as A on Qualys tests ([StackExchange Server 1](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=meta.stackexchange.com&s=104.16.12.13), [StackExchange Server 2](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=meta.stackexchange.com&s=104.16.13.13)), and [SuperUser](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=superuser.com)), yet it is not easy to trust the site co-certed with an unrelated organization or registered to CloudFlare (I cannot easily know I'm not being MITM'ed).

Would be grateful for clarifications or prompt dupe-closure.

Comment: I guess it's all part of the [Better https support for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites), but prefer to let a dev reply with specific details here than close as dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SuperUser certificate is issued to CN: ssl4121.cloudflare.com, not superuser.com, and shared with an unrelated site (https://wimdu.co.uk)

From here the certificate for superuser.com is for CN `ssl4121.cloudflare.com` but includes `*.superuser.com` and `superuser.com` as subject alternative names, which means everything is fine. And that the certificate is shared with other domains is normal for CDN (content delivery networks) like Cloudflare.

> StackExchange certificate is issued to O: CloudFlare, Inc.

This is normal too, since the site is managed by the Cloudflare CDN.

> it is not easy to trust the site co-certed with an unrelated organization or registered to CloudFlare (I cannot easily know I'm not being MITM'ed)

A certificate does not say anything about trust related to the user. It is only used to make sure, that the site you see in the URL is the site you actually connect too and thus no man-in-the-middle attack is done. 
See also [What is the real use of certificates on the web?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84793/what-is-the-real-use-of-certificates-on-the-web/84796#84796)

Comment: Strangely, some of those certs I've seen don't even mention anything but that cloudflare host – so browsers naturally *have to* choke on that. Would you count that normal as well? The one I currently get on meta.softwarerecs e.g. is issued for `ssl8217.cloudflare.com` only. No other host names or wildcards mentioned here.

Comment: There is no `meta.softwarerecs` domain and I cannot detect what you really mean.

Comment: Click here: https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The subject alternative section for the certificate of this site contains DNS Name: ssl8217.cloudflare.com,
DNS Name: *.stackexchange.com,
DNS Name: stackexchange.com. But the problem is that `*.stackexchange.com` matches only `whatever.stackexchange.com` but not `meta.whatever.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: I'm currently not at my own (Linux) machine, so I cannot run a "deep check". Firefox on Windows doesn't show any reference other than that cloudshare host when viewing the certificate. But if you say those refs are in then yes, that's most likely the culprit. And probably no way around that, as no CA issues certs for `*.*.domain.com` I guess (if such a CN would even be technically valid, which I don't know). Would there be any work-around available? Even when accepting that one cert, next time it could be a different cloudflare server. CN=*.cloudflare.com would be helpful at least …

Comment: Only a single leftmost wildcard can be used in a name, which means there must be entries for `*.foo.example.com`, `*.bar.example.com` etc. A  way might be to not use `foo.stackexchange.com` and `meta.foo.stackexchange.com` but instead `foo.stackexchange.com` and `foo.meta.stackexchange.com`. Then a single `*.meta.stackexchange.com` entry in the certificate would be enough. But  while this sound nice for the certificates it might conflict with necessary cookie and same origin policies.

Comment: I see the problem; so there's no really "clean" solution here. If Cloudflare would use a wildcard for their servers (`*.cloudflare.com`), one would at least have to accept only one "strange cert"; but I guess I'd rather use plain http than having such an "egg in the basket". Unfortunate as it is, I have to accept the "status quo" then. Thanks for the background, Steffen!