# Bad SSL/TLS at Stack Exchange: Cloudflares SSL certificates and sometimes no HTTPS at all

Tags: discussion, status-completed, ssl, security

## Cloudflare

Cloudflare has the options Universal/Flexible SSL, which basically allow websites to serve their website over HTTPS by using a certificate from Cloudflare.

Besides the fact that Cloudflare always acts as a man-in-the-middle, here the connections from Cloudflare to the origin server [may not be encrypted](https://scotthelme.co.uk/cloudflares-great-new-features-and-why-i-wont-use-them/) (with Universal/Flexible SSL), or Full SSL only use a self-signed certificate which is also quite unsecure.

[This may not be changed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97920/cloudflares-free-ssl-options-require-trusting-them-what-could-they-do-to-chang), but at least they have two options which may be considered quite secure (Keyless SSL and Full SSL (Strict)) as there the real Stack Exchange certificate is used.

AFAIK, unless Stack Exchange uses Keyless SSL, you do not know what mode they use, because in all other modes you only see a certificate issued for `ssl*.cloudflare.com` with an Subject Alternative Name for the real domain. [This already caused some confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252349/stackexchange-certificate-issued-for-cloudflare-superuser-certificate-issued-to).

## meta.*.stackexchange.com

But it's getting worse: You have no HTTPS at all on these sites. E.g. look at one of the most ironic domains: https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/ or https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/
[This is a known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216384/untrusted-connection-when-visiting-meta-stack-exchange-sites), and I know you cannot solve it, because you cannot use a wildcard TLS certificate there. There was also a [blog post](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) about this issue (BTW: Site uses Cloudflare SSL too).

*But* this blog post is from 2013. Come on: We have 2016 now and you neither have other subdomains nor HTTPS on these domains. Nowadays we even have automated [CAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) (Let's Encrypt) so there is really *no* problem to get certificates for all these domains. And we have HTTP headers [which can make the migrating from HTTP to HTTPS very easy (see scotthelme.co.uk/migrating-from-http-to-https-ease-the-pain-with-csp-and-hsts/).

Some of the arguments in the blog post are already outdated (e.g. the Google rank argument [today Google even ranks sites with HTTPS heigher] and the third-parties [AFAIK all of the listed ones there support HTTPS now]) and all in all you also did not keep your promise:

> We’ll be working on it over the next 6-8 weeks.

in the blog post

> We will be working on it in 2014

in [SSL error on meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8061/ssl-error-on-meta#answer-8099)

Also note it is a big security risk when you send cookies over unsecure connections. I don't know how your authentication system is designed, because with different cookies for insecure connections (over HTTP) and secure ones (over HTTPS) you can mitigate this risk a bit - similar to the way Amazon does it, but this is still a bad workaround.

## When will we get HTTPS?

Additionally there are still sites with Mixed Content errors (on the home page!). E.g. on https://movies.stackexchange.com/ you load an image from http://area51.stackexchange.com. Just adding an `s` there would fix this.

Even big news sites have managed (see developer.washingtonpost.com/pb/blog/post/2015/12/10/moving-the-washington-post-to-https) to switch to HTTPS and according to their blog post this was not an easy step either.
**In 2016 it's amazing to see such a famous site to not have complete HTTPS support.**

Comment: That's **not a duplicate**. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites is nearly as old as the blog post I linked and the small 2015 edit only says that they now have a A rating. This addresses nothing I mention in this post.
Please reopen this, thanks.

Comment: And when looking at the test result I see even more issues: An A rating is nothing special. With Cloudflare every site can get this easily.
But at least there should be an HSTS header and it must not forward to `http://stackoverflow.com`...

Comment: *all in all you also did not keep your promise: We’ll be working on it over the next 6-8 weeks.* Actually, that timeframe still applies.

Comment: @rugk There's simply nothing more to add to this. **We're working on it.** It's not done yet, but we're getting closer and closer every day. Be patient and we'll have full HTTPS support when we've worked out all the kinks.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that "6 to 8 weeks" is an SO in-joke that should probably be read as "We're working on it, but we have no idea of the timeframe". See also: [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/262425)

Comment: BiscuitBaker 20 Indeed that's *very* helpful. I didn't know this is a joke and saying "the timeframe applies" like @Won't is a also strange here as it is no time frame. Anyway the *"We will be working on it in 2014"* is no joke and there you see that they wanted to do it two years before...

Comment: @animuson Nice to hear that...

Comment: This has been rolled out, see https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/ for (lots of) details.

Comment: @NickCraver Yeah, issue fixed. But you were to slow, I already read it. (just now)
Now going to build a bot trying to find datacenters and login with "prickles"…