# Privacy error on some .SE sites

Tags: bug, status-declined, privacy, ssl

Google Chrome 41.0.2272.118, Ubuntu 14.04

[image: Your connection is not private]

This is the second time I have had this error in the last week or so. Is this a bug on my part, or is there something up with the SE security certificate?

I've changed to bug because of [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252823/privacy-error-on-some-se-sites#comment825597_252823):

> No, it's something Stack Exchange would have to fix. Chrome is following the rules. But considering the whole `meta.*.stackexchange.com` dilemma is what's been holding up a lot of the HTTPS support, I doubt they're going to come up with any kind of fix for the `www.*.stackexchange.com` redirect problem. –  animuson♦

Comment: Did you accidentally change the time on your computer?

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq no, the time is 1 second off. Could it be a daylight savings time issue? It also is only EL&U atm...

Comment: Get rid of the "www" that's what cause this scary warning. Proper link is `https://english.stackexchange.com/`. Also report where you saw such a link and it better be changed in there as well.

Comment: @Tim Once I was fooling around with my computer's time, and changed it to Dec 31, 2099. It said the certificated expired.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did wonder this, and I tested it with another www.*.se site [lifehacks.se] but that went through. That link was my own, I'll update it.

Comment: Mhmmm, the server would redirect you to the non-www version if the page processed, but since the certificate is not valid for the www versions, Chrome stops you before you get to the redirect that would send you back to a *valid* URL for the certificate.

Comment: So it is a Chrome thing? Or is it because I clicked a link rather than typed?

Comment: No, it's something Stack Exchange would have to fix. Chrome is following the rules. But considering the whole meta.*.stackexchange.com dilemma is what's been holding up a lot of the HTTPS support, I doubt they're going to come up with any kind of fix for the www.*.stackexchange.com redirect problem.

Comment: Should I change to [tag:bug] then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Where did you find a link with `www` in it? We don't really use or support that subdomain.

Comment: @AdamLear It was me typing it into a bookmark page. I have since updated it, but @animuson said it was an SE bug with the redirection not working?`

Comment: @Tim The redirection works - but when you hit a site over HTTPS, it needs a valid certificate... So that's where Chrome comes in, before the redirect kicks in.

Comment: Okay. So does this count as status by design? It doesn't sound like you guys can fix this...?

Comment: @animuson We. We aren't going to come up with any kind of fix. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have a redirect in place to correct `www.*.stackexchange.com` URLs into the correct `*.stackexchange.com` form. This works fine when HTTPS isn't involved, but the second you combine the two, the redirect will be impossible without a valid certificate.

Since `www` isn't actually a valid subdomain for us and is maintained purely for legacy reasons (hello, 1990s!), we're not going to set up hundreds of certificates to support this case. I recommend not bookmarking `https://www.*.stackexchange.com`. :)

Comment: What about the non se domains? [so] and [ubuntu.se] for example? Do they support www or is it the whole network?

Comment: @Tim Try them and see.

Comment: They redirect successfully, as do the se domains (normally). I guess it is the same?

Comment: Certificates cover one subdomain, so `*.stackoverflow.com` is fine, `*.stackexchange.com` is fine, `*.english.stackexchange.com` is fine, etc. But, say, `meta.*.stackexchange.com` is not - you can't have a wildcard in the middle of a cert.

Comment: Which is why there is the https issues. I see :)