# SSL cert continues to fail to cover second-level subdomains

Tags: support, login, ssl, subdomains

If you try to log in from a meta site (`meta.*.stackexchange.com`), you get an "Untrusted Connection" from Firefox, even without HTTPS Everywhere enabled.

For example, I just tried this on `meta.law.stackexchange.com` and the certificate appears to be only valid for `ssl8217.cloudflare.com, *.stackexchange.com, stackexchange.com` domains, thus causing `ssl_error_bad_cert_domain`.

It has been over two years since this issue was reported, and it continues to appear.

Here's one version of the security warning, on Firefox:

[image]

It's 2016, and we should be having reliable HTTPS coverage by now, at least for login.

Comment: Answer went poof along with discussion. Isn't that wonderful.

Comment: The text format makes it a little hard to tell if your second sentence is serious or sarcastic.