# Could image links on uploads to i.stack.imgur.com use HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Tags: feature-request, ssl, uploader

The StackExchange network has seen [some improvements on HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116782/191939) in the last few years, and adding an image is now as simple as it gets.

However, if I upload an image to imgur, the resulting link will be

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/random.extension
```

instead of the HTTPS one

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/random.extension
```

although [HTTPS is fully supported by imgur](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=imgur.com). This leads to a security warning:

[image: security warning in Firefox]

This question should also contain a security warning, because the image above also has been uploaded to i.stack.imgur.com and uses HTTP.

So, could the link provided by the image inserter (<kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd>) be HTTPS by default?