# Can we fix the insecure Open Search and broken icon?

Tags: discussion, bug, search

On the sites I checked I noticed an `/opensearch.xml` file. For example:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/opensearch.xml
- https://serverfault.com/opensearch.xml
- https://stackexchange.com/opensearch.xml

First of all the `link`-tag point to a relative path which is good. *Off-topic: You could decide to load that XML file (or the whole site) always over SSL only. HSTS, HPKP et cetera. Nevertheless, that's not my point here.*

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Server Fault" href="/opensearch.xml">
```

My point is, when you look in the actual `opensearch.xml` file. You see that search queries are always send over HTTP. Why is is possibly like that?

```
  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="https://serverfault.com/search?q={searchTerms}"></Url>
```

Please change this to `https://` by default for all sites. It's just a search query but it looks ridiculous to send user-data over HTTP while SSL is fully functional.

Secondly the attempt to fetch HTTP or HTTPS for the image like this:

```
<Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">//sstatic.net/Sites/serverfault/img/favicon.ico</Image>
```

Is broken (at least in Firefox) as you can see on the image below.

[image: broken icon]

This should probably be static to HTTP. HTTPS will likely also work but seems unnecessary for an icon when the whole site is available over HTTP anyway.

I'd recommend to change the following on all Stack Family sites:

1. the icon from `//` to `http://`,
2. the `{searchTerms}` template url from `http://` to `https://`.

Comment: HTTPS is [not fully supported yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites) on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @hichris123 then at least support it on the login page and search page (or all pages with forms) and force the template URL to HTTPS anyway.

Comment: The login page has been HTTPS for a long while. Everything else is HTTP by default, there's still a lot of work left (as per-site metas are very challenging to make work with TLS).

Comment: This will pick up in full force as soon as I'm back from vacation at the beginning of August.