# Move child metas from meta.sitename.SE to sitename.SE/meta

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, ssl

Currently, every SE site has two domain names - one for the site itself (`sitename.stackexchange.com`) and one for its meta (`meta.sitename.stackexchange.com`). This makes it hard to [improve HTTPS support network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites) because of the limitations on domain certificates [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) pointed out [here](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/).

One of these limitations has a ***really*** easy solution (emphasis added):

> [Section 3.1 of RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) is very open/ambiguous on wildcard usage, it states:
>
> > Names may contain the wildcard character `*` which is considered to match any single domain name component or component fragment. E.g., `*.a.com` matches `foo.a.com` but not `bar.foo.a.com`. `f*.com` matches `foo.com` but not `bar.com`.
>
> It doesn’t really disallow `meta.*.stackexchange.com` or `*.*.meta.stackexchange.com`. So far so good…then some jerk tried to make a certificate for `***.com**` which obviously wasn’t good, so that was revoked and disallowed. So what happened? Some other jerk went and tried `***.*.com**`. Well, that ruined it for everyone. Thanks, jerks.
>
> The rules were further clarified in [Section 6.4.3 of RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.3) which says (emphasis mine):
>
> > The client SHOULD NOT attempt to match a presented identifier in which the wildcard character comprises a label other than the left-most label (e.g., do not match `bar.*.example.net`)
>
> This means **no `*.*.stackexchange.com` or `meta.*.stackexchange.com`**. Enough major browsers conform to this RFC that it’s a non-option.

Then **why don't we host per-site metas as `sitename.stackexchange.com/meta` instead of `meta.sitename.stackexchange.com`?** That way, we can host all sites and their metas with one single certificate for `*.stackexchange.com`.

---

I guess most of you have two major concerns on this, so here are solutions to them as well:

1. **This will break existing links to content on child metas, won't it?**

   [HTTP has a built-in for that.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) As for future sites, the solution is to not even talk about `meta.sitename.stackexchange.com`.
2. **What about sites that have their own domains?**

   Since they're not affected by this limitation, there's no need to move the metas of [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net), [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) and [Super User](http://superuser.com). That means we can simply make `/meta` redirect to the respective meta of each site.

   [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) doesn't even have its own meta.

   While [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) isn't affected either, localized Stack Overflows are affected because their metas' domains look like `meta.*.stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: This is not necessary. We're already moving to the *.meta.stackexchange.com to solve the HTTPS problem. It's being actively worked on.

Answer (score 6):

[Adam Lear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333419/6083675) says they already have plans in motion for SSL:

> I can tell you that it's being worked on (next step: moving meta sites to the *.meta.stackexchange.com URL scheme from meta.*.stackexchange.com), but there is no deadline or ETA. We're solving issues, paying down tech debt as needed, and making progress as time allows amidst everything else that's currently in progress.