# "Your connection to this site is not private"

Tags: support, ssl, http

[image]

I'm using Chrome and since a few days/weeks ago I started to see this. Why is that?

Comment: yes, disabled all of them, but still same

Comment: That's just because the page is not served via HTTPS. Nothing specific to SE.

Comment: @Mat Yes, I thought It redirects automatically to 443. Should it be?

Comment: Nope, that's not implemented yet. You'll find lots of discussion about SE moving to https on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This got nothing to do with Stack Exchange.

This icon and message appear in Chrome browser, since its latest version, for any site that is not served over https, e.g. http://java.com

> [image]

(Just an example of a big major site which also does not use SSL by default.)

This is also discussed on [Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/PIBvM-T-qWU;context-place=forum/chrome), where one of the answers clearly says:

> The "i inside a circle" is just the new Material Design UI graphical update only.  In the previous UI, regular HTTP webpages showed a "blank page icon".
>
> When you click on it, the information displayed is exactly the same.  Regular HTTP webpages are "connection to this site is not private", as they have always never been private.
>
> Only connections to secure, encrypted HTTPS webpages are private, and those websites will show with a closed Green Lock.