# Meta-site flairs seem to be broken

Tags: bug, status-planned, images, flair

<sup>I assume this is something to do with [the big HTTPS change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/278659) ...</sup>

Just now I was fixing up some broken images on meta sites by changing http to https. Many of these were on pro-tem mod nominations, which often include the main-site, meta-site, and network flairs of the nominee. But for some reason, the meta-site flairs aren't working.

For example, `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/flair/31394.png` works to give this image:

[image: My SFF user flair]

but `https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/31394.png` doesn't display an image at all:

[image: My SFF meta user flair - failed]

(In case anyone else isn't seeing the same error, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTCKg.png) is what I see for this post.)

I've also tried `http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/users/flair/31394.png` (gives the now-usual "must use HTTPS" error) and `https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/31394.png` (doesn't work at all, or at least gives the same non-functioning image as meta.scifi).

What gives?

Comment: HTTPS has never worked on meta sites. The transition forcing flairs to be HTTPS broke them on Meta. This will be fixed when they change the meta sites to be HTTPS too.

Comment: Both display fine for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0C0R.png. For what it's worth, I'm on latest Opera and using HTTPS everywhere (maybe it's relevant).

Comment: @Tim It's very odd: posts with HTTP images on meta *look* fine (they haven't devolved to "alt text + link" like on main), but when I go to edit any such post, the "HTTP images don't work" error box still comes up.

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/users/flair/31394.png works for me as well.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Is that an HTTP link or an HTTPS link? I can't tell from your comment.

Comment: Comment stripped the http part, but both work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTPS issue on meta, but no issue on main](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292055/https-issue-on-meta-but-no-issue-on-main)

Comment: @SagarV That question itself is a duplicate of a duplicate of [this feature request from 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116782/278659). My question is much more specific than that one.