# Why hadn't SE had HTTPS for a long time?

Tags: discussion, ssl, security, http

I'm novice in security, but after reading the post [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/260800) I'm confused. As in the answer of [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186399/260800), having an SSL certificate is not expensive anymore, so I can't imagine why we hadn't had it for a long time. I mean, I had thought that there was always a green padlock whenever I visited Stack Exchange.

I would like to have an answer that contains not so much technical terms, unlike the [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/260800) post.

Comment: _"I'm novice here"_ Huh?? _"I know that this is googlable ..."_  Research effort is essential for any SE site.

Comment: Is this better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> having an SSL certificate is not expensive anymore, so I can't imagine why we hadn't had it for a long time

Certificates are cheap, but implementing HTTPS on a site that always has run under HTTP is not. There were a lot of issues the team had to deal with: links, images, meta sites, etc.

It is very well possible you've visited Stack Exchange main sites over HTTPS for a while. They have had a certificate for years, but support was not 100% well. Meta sites didn't work over HTTPS (they had an invalid certificate).

They did use HTTPS for critical parts of the site, like login, etc. Other parts were HTTP with no active support for HTTPS. Until now.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression that implementing SSL is cheap and **easy**.

Comment: Not if you have a site with `http://` in a dozen places in the code.

Comment: The meta sites worked with https, so I used them years long. Although the invalid cert resulted, that you weren't protected from mitm attacks (but, against the usual, passive eavesdropping, yes). I used a patched https everywhere for that.

Comment: @Pat but I guess you only need to search and replace them? Is that for large code even search and replace requires higher caution?

Comment: Find and replace is often the fastest way to screw up your code without knowing it.

Comment: @Ooker when Patrick says in about a dozen places in the code, he means closer to a few thousand places. And you've got to go through all of those without breaking anything, and keeping the site online while you're doing it.

Comment: Indeed. And what about code that assumes an url starts with 7 characters that represents the protocol. Instead of 8 with HTTPS.

Comment: ugh, there's even a code that requires the number of characters representing the protocol are exactly 7? Why don't they just assign the link to a variable/module, and fixing that variable/module instead?

Comment: @Ooker - It's a nice thought.  But your suggestion has the same problem as simply increasing the count by 1.  It still has to work, on a live website, and without breaking it.

Comment: @Ramhound the more I know about coding, the more I naive about it...

Comment: @Ooker I am not saying they didn't switch to a variable just saying they would have had to still test it because they hadn't originally used one.

Comment: @Ramhound I mean, even when I know that changing anything should go along with careful since the site is large, I just didn't expect that tiny change can be so time-consuming.